# What's the best way to manage large ObjectID arrays in mongoose / mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

In this case:

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "content": {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    "user": {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User"
    },
    "created": {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    "comments": [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
})
```

I want to be able to get 10 comments at a time, but I see no way to do that without having to get all the comments every time.

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uncorrelated lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to join collections and limit to 10. Here is an example, I used `String` for `_id` for easy understanding.

- `$lookup` - there are two lookup, I used here uncorrelated lookup where you can do parallel aggregation in joining collection. `$match` helps to conditionally join documents. `$expr` is a must to use inside the `$match` when you use uncorrelated lookup. `$limit` helps to limit the documents. If you need you can add more stages to perform aggregation inside the pipeline

Here is the script

```
db.PostSchema.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Comment",
      let: {
        cId: "$comments"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              _id: {
                in: [
                  "$$cId"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 10
        }
      ],
      "as": "comments"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KPBfM9p53vZ)**